# Group permission inheritance and umask

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, shell, file-permissions

Edit: in my case virtual_use_local_privs=TRUE did the trick.

i'm trying to force `newly created files and directories`  inside foo/ directory to be `owned by nginx` user and to set the right permissions so `nginx group users can execute and modify` them if needed.

The whole thing is i've just configured `vsftpd` service where my `virtual` users act as `vsftpd user`, where vsftpd is a real user with no shell.

After login, each user is `chrooted` on a directory owned by `user vsftpd` and `group nginx`. To accomplish that i created the chroot directory:

```
mkdir chroot/
```

and then gave the default permissions:

```
chown -R vsftpd:nginx chroot/
```

and then enabled SGUID:

```
chmod -R g+s chroot/
```

Right here, when a vsftpd user creates a directory default permissions are `vsftpd:nginx` but default permissions for files are `nginx:nginx` which is not what i want.

Then, as i need `nginx` user's group to run and modify files if need i setted umask '0022' through vsftpd config but i think i'm going in the wrong way. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advanced!

Edit:

The `setfacl` command helped a lot, but i'm still having issues with umask.

I run `setfacl -R -m d:u:vsftpd:rwx,d:g:nginx:rwx,d:m:rx,d:o::r chroot/` where `getfacl chroot/` returns:

```
# owner: vsftpd
# group: nginx
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
default:user::rwx
default:user:vsftpd:rwx         #effective:r-x
default:group::rwx              #effective:r-x
default:group:nginx:rwx         #effective:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::r--
```

but uploading new files leaves the following permissions `-rw-------+ 1 vsftpd nginx    25 feb  7 13:14 info.php`

Note umask setting on vsftpd.conf is set to 1002

Where am i going wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try uploading with different ftp clients (eg filezilla for windows)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use acl's to get the user to always be set to nginx.  You would mount the filesystem with acl option, then use

```
setfacl -m d:u:nginx:rwx,d:g:nginx:rw chroot
```

(or rw if you don't need executable).  Then all files created in the dir will have additional perms giving nginx ownership (even if the primary owner, that shown when ls is used, is a different user).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! The setfacl command helped a lot, but i'm still having issues with umask. I run setfacl -R -m d:u:vsftpd:rwx,d:g:nginx:rwx,d:m:rx,d:o::r chroot/ but uploading new files leaves the following permissions -rw-------+ 1 vsftpd nginx    25 feb  7 13:14 info.php Note umask on vsftpd.conf is set to 1002

Comment: Remember, umask is the reverse of 777, so if your umask is set to 002, then the perms of a new file will be 775.  I don't see anything anywhere that will set any other bits than read, write, and execute.  Your result seems to be consistent.  If you run getfacl on the file, you will see that it got the default acl applied to it.

Comment: Thanks, i see umask i set in the right way but as you can see file uploads doesn't seem to obey the default umask, isn't it? Must be something wrong somewhere

Comment: No your uploaded file looks fine to me.  Correct perms for the umask, and if you do a getfacl on the file, you will see the correct perms.  umask and default acls are two different things.

Comment: Finally virtual_use_local_privs=TRUE did the trick, now vsftpd respects acl settings. Thanks a lot lsd! :D